# Authorise a JAAS session by NT Group?

Tags: java, active-directory, jaas, active-directory-group

Is it possible to authorise JAAS sessions based on membership of NT Groups?

Comment: Need some more information.... Do you mean authorize instead of authenticate? Are you asking for something "out of the box"? Or are you comfortable with a custom module? Theoretically, AD is just an LDAP store, so we can do all manner of fun things with it. In practice, it lays things out differently from a "traditional" directory, so standard modules are limited.

Comment: I mean if they're in the group, I let them have access to the information. Happy with a custom module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it is user level only. 
http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/jaas/JAASRefGuide.html

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/jre/api/security/jaas/spec/com/sun/security/auth/module/LdapLoginModule.html

(ie administration is via a policy file - not possible to change authorisation based on NT Group.)